# EXTRACT Hour Function is not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a select query where i take difference between two timestamps

```
select EXTRACT (HOUR FROM (systimestamp-queuereceiveddate(a,b))) 
  from dual
```

The `queuereceived` date function also returns a timestamp. I am able to extract days by using the extract function but not hours.

Please advise on this

Comment: "not working as unexpected" is unhelpful.  Please describe what you expect to happen and what actually happens, including any error messages.

Comment: @APC "not working as *un*expected"? That sentence makes my brain hurt :-)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - I apologise for the distress my typo has acused you.

Answer (score 3):

Extracting the hour certainly works:

```
select systimestamp - (systimestamp - 27.5/24) as diff,
    extract(day from systimestamp - (systimestamp - 27.5/24)) as diff_day,
    extract(hour from systimestamp - (systimestamp - 27.5/24)) as diff_hour
from dual;

DIFF                             DIFF_DAY  DIFF_HOUR
------------------------------ ---------- ----------
+000000001 03:30:00.584929              1          3
```

*If* you're expecting it to show the total number of hours, if the difference is more than one day, then you misunderstand what the [extract function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions059.htm) is doing, and you'll need to calculate a total by multiplying the `day` value by 24 and adding that to the `hour` value:

```
select systimestamp - (systimestamp - 27.5/24) as diff,
    extract(day from systimestamp - (systimestamp - 27.5/24))  * 24
        + extract(hour from systimestamp - (systimestamp - 27.5/24))
        as diff_hour_total
from dual;

DIFF                           DIFF_HOUR_TOTAL
------------------------------ ---------------
+000000001 03:30:00.612830                  27
```

Of course I'm guessing since you haven't explained the problem you're seeing, but since the function does work this is the only thing I can think you mean...

Comment: Yeah the hours difference is more than one day. So for example my Queue Received Date function returns a date which is 3 days ols. I need to extract the hours from that

Comment: What do you mean the 'extract the hours'? You still haven't said what you want to see. If it's more than three days old are you expecting a value of 72 (or higher)? That isn't really an 'extract', at least in terms of that function.

Comment: Yes i expect to see 72 as the value if the exact difference is 3 days. So yes the answer you gave above definitely works